# Does the original jutsu user feel anything when a shadow clone is dispersed forcefully?

Tags: naruto

According to the wiki,

> While the technique can be extremely beneficial, attempting to use multiple clones for training purposes can be mentally harmful to the user, as not only is all the experience collected by the user, but so is all the mental stress from training each clone

Now, when a clone is destroyed, there must be some mental stress involved. So does Naruto (or anyone else) feel anything when their shadow clones are dispersed?

Nothing has been shown to indicate this (at least in the anime). I was wondering why this would not be applicable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, actually the mental stress involved when a clone is forcefully destroyed being transferred to the original *has* been showed on a number of occasions in the anime, including once *before* the timeskip.

During the Invasion of Konoha arc:

> When Naruto fights Gaara, Gaara goes into the Ichibi Shukaku mode, and Naruto attacks Gaara/Shukaku using 1000 clones with the Naruto Niisen Rendan (Naruto Two Thousand Combo). He then attempts the Naruto Yonsen Rendan (Naruto Four Thousand Combo), but Shukaku fights back and destroys nearly all the clones. As Naruto is forced back, he exclaims, "That hurt a lot".

Later after the timeskip, when Kakashi tells Naruto that the pain experienced by the clone is transferred to the user, Naruto says in a dejected/annoyed tone, "I knew that already."

Comment: I think the Gaara thing is mainly because Shukakku hit the original as well. It's possible though.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Yes, maybe it is as you said. That particular instance stood out (for me) because earlier the original Naruto took several direct hits, stronger than that one, and yet he did not say anything. So I thought that he *really* felt the pain of about 1000 clones getting destroyed. But then, anime characters do not always react consistently to events, so who knows about that?

Comment: Great discussion! +1

Answer (score 4):

Yes, he does feel something. It was shown in the episodes when Naruto was training with Kakashi and Yamato (I don't remember exact eisodes, but it was about when Kakashi gave Naruto the paper to test his chakra affinity).

Kakashi Told Naruto that when he could increase the learning speed by using clones, because when the clone is destroyed, all the new knowledge it acquired is immediately transfered to the technique user.

Naruto said that he had never known about it, and Kakashi asked him to make a clone and to order the clone to follow him. They moved rather far away from Naruto, and Kakashi told the clone something, I think it was a joke, but I don't remember well. Then, after they got back and Naruto released the technique, he immideately had the knowledge of what Kakashi had said to the clone.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But that would come under knowledge. I was wondering f the shadow clone feels anything while being dispersed and whether the user feels that as well. The expressions on the shadow clones' faces seem to indicate that they feel something atleast.

Answer (score 3):

You basically answered your own question. It is indeed stated that Naruto receives the experience, mental stress and chakra of the clone. When a clone is destroyed, it, of course, had mental stress (as it just got attacked and killed).

Most of the times you do not see this, either because Naruto is used to this and has an immense capacity to endure this, or because the technique would become meaningless if he could not use it due to all the stress. (I suspect the latter)

Although, during the training where he uses his clones to decrease the training duration, it became clear that is was very hard on him due to the mental stress he received of his clones.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is another possibility: The clones disperse too quickly under attack or the stress is only passed when the jutsu is dispelled by Naruto (or others)

Comment: Well they tend to endure one or two blows (some even more), so I guess they do get some mental stress (which should/is pass(ed) on to Naruto).

Comment: Correct. But it never seems to slow Naruto down (though a single blow against him was sufficient to slow him down as a kid)

Answer (score 3):

The clones definitely feel something, as they were seen to have facial expressions, as well as groaning to indicate they feel pain.

That feeling does not seem to go through back to the original. Even though knowledge, experience and even exaughstion seems to go back, there probably is a protection against physical injury and pain (otherwise, it wouldn't make the technique so useful).

In short, he does *know* when his clones are destroyed (because their knowledge is reflected back at him), but he doesn't feel their pain when they are hit by shuriken or receive fatal injuries.

Comment: Maybe he just doesn't feel anything because the clones are destroyed and not killed. They disperse once they got hit by a shuriken or receive a fatal injury. So they might not even feel something when they got destroyed. It's not like a "normal" Human being killed, they don't suffer injuries or bleeding to death, they just got released.

Comment: They do groan in pain, and their face suggests that they feel something

Answer (score 1):

I think mental knowledge and experiences are transferred to the original once disperesed, but not physical pain. If that were the case, using the shadow clone jutsu would only be too risky and only used for emergencies.

I was actually wondering about the opposite scenario. Do the shadow clones share injuries of the original. For example, when kabuto severed the muscle in naruto's leg out, did the shadow clone created afterwards also have a severed muscle in the leg.

Comment: You could add the second para as a separate question. It is a good one.

Comment: The physical pain might not be transferred, but the knowledge probably is. Induced empathy could be rather severe.